# Derivative of the Wasserstein Metric between two Gaussians

Tags: stochastic-calculus, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition, wasserstein

I am trying to take the derivative of the squared Wasserstein metric between two Gaussian probability densities, which is given by $W_2^2(q_0, q_1) = \| \boldsymbol{\mu}_0 - \boldsymbol{\mu}_1 \|_2^2 + \text{tr}[\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_0 + \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_1 - 2 (\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_0^{1/2} \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_1 \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_0^{1/2})^{1/2} ]$, where $q_0 = \mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{\mu}_0,\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_0)$ and $q_1 = \mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{\mu}_1,\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_1)$, are Gaussian densities. I need the derivative $\frac{\partial W_2^2(q_0,q_1)}{\partial \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_1}$; however, I am unsure how to take the derivative of the matrix square-root within the trace term.

Comment: Apply the inverse function theorem to the derivative of $X↦X^2$

Comment: Something like
$$\eqalign{
\def\S{\Sigma}\def\SX{\S_1}\def\SQ{\S_0^{1/2}}
\frac{\partial W^2}{\partial\SX}
 &= I - \SQ\left(\SQ\SX\SQ\right)^{-1/2}\SQ \\
}$$

Comment: Thanks for the help! Is this valid for any valid matrix square root? Or is it only true for ${\boldsymbol{X} = \boldsymbol{S}\boldsymbol{S}}$ rather than $\boldsymbol{X} = \boldsymbol{S}\boldsymbol{S}^T$.

Comment: Usually, the matrix square root is considered only for the subset of symmetric positive-semi-definite matrices, because only there one can define a unique square root that is also symmetric positive-semi-definite, i.e. if $A$ is spd matrix, then there is a unique spd matrix $B$ such that $A=B^⊤B = B^2 = BB^⊤$.

For a general matrix $A$ there can be infinitely many solutions to $A=B^2$.